# if div id contains text X, change text doesnt work

Tags: jquery, replace, contains

This is the code which returns the ID of a category in a table cell:

```
<td headers="el_state" align="left" valign="top">
   <div id="el_preis">
      <?php echo $row->catid ? $this->escape($row->catid) : '-';?>
   </div>
</td>
```

There are 8 different categories. I tried to change the ID with the price with the following code. Just the ID in the first row changes.

```
$("#el_preis:contains('1')").html("295 €");
$("#el_preis:contains('2')").html("295 €");
$("#el_preis:contains('3')").html("65 €");
$("#el_preis:contains('4')").html("115 €");
$("#el_preis:contains('5')").html("200 €");
$("#el_preis:contains('6')").html("200 €");
$("#el_preis:contains('7')").html("200 €");
$("#el_preis:contains('8')").html("295 €");
```

What do i have to change?

Comment: Where does `$this` come from? Is the HTML generated properly?

Comment: "Just the ID in the first row changes." Are you using the same ID for multiple DIVs? IDs are supposed to be unique; you should use a common class instead.

Comment: Show us the generated HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is working correctly:
http://jsfiddle.net/imac/zTAW3/

The problem is not on the jQuery code.

Anyway, If you are gonna do this on load, I would recommend to do it on the server side if possible. It will be faster and won't overload the client with unnecessary operations.

You could use a function in PHP to return the price depending on the category. A simple `switch`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Did it with switch and cases.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
($("#el_preis").html().indexOf("1") != -1)?$("#el_preis").html("295 €"):console.log("contains no 1")
```